# Data inside of nested map is visible but not accesable

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I have really conufusing problem.
I have one document.

[image]

I get this document in my flutter app.

when I print that line

> `print(recentReport["tesvikiye"]);`

there is no problem.

output:

> {ItemsSold: 1, BestSelller: fgh, Revenue: 676.0}

as excepted.

However, when I put

> `print(recentReport["tesvikiye"]["BestSeller"]);`

I got `null`.

It makes no sense at all. I am able to see data when I acces outer map. But when I try acces data through inner map, data suddenly becomes. null.

other fields like

> `print(recentReport["tesvikiye"]["ItemsSold"]);`
> `print(recentReport["tesvikiye"]["Revenue"]);`

works as they should. I don't have general problem for accesing inner map values. Only BestSeller field.

also, I don't have problem for other documents.

> `print(recentReport["fenerbahce"]["BestSeller"]);` or > `print(recentReport["kozyatagi"]["BestSeller"]);`

returns value not null. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `BestSelller` in your document not `BestSeller` for `tesvikiye`

```
print(recentReport["tesvikiye"]["BestSeller"]);
```

Replace `BestSeller` with `BestSelller` in the above code.

Then you will get the data properly.

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't know how I couldn't see that.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you, Please accept the answer.